# Xcode Cloud has no write permission when running Swift Package Plugin

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, xcode-cloud, swift-package-plugin

I have this Plugin

```swift
struct Main: BuildToolPlugin {
  func createBuildCommands(context: PluginContext, target: Target) async throws -> [Command] {
    let inputFolder = target.directory.appending("Image")
    let output = context.pluginWorkDirectory.appending("GeneratedImageAssets.swift")
    return [
      .buildCommand(
        displayName: "Running ImageAssets parser",
        executable: try context.tool(named: "ImageAssetsParser").path,
        arguments: [inputFolder.string, output.string],
        environment: [:],
        inputFiles: [inputFolder],
        outputFiles: [output]
      )
    ]
  }
}
```

`ImageAssetsParser` is an `executableTarget` in swift code that scan folders and write them in the `output` folder sent by the plugin.

Although locally it works everything, on Xcode Cloud I got permission error:

[image]

The weird things is that I have also a `prebuildCommand` plugin that uses `swiftgen`, as an `artifactbundle` and it works properly, it writes in same folder.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months, by chance I found what was the issue!

In my plugin implementation I write the file through

```swift
"""
// auto generated swift file

// ... the content
""".write(to: output, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

Using `atomically: true` is the issue: this means that swift writes the entire content into a temporary file placed somewhere else and Xcode Cloud doesn't have permission in this moment!

Using `atomically: false` the file is written directly into our output file, which is the `context.pluginWorkDirectory.appending("GeneratedImageAssets.swift")` and permissions here hare granted!!

Answer (score -2):

I had similar issue. Try replacing `buildCommand` with `preBuildCommand` that fixed the issue.

Comment: I cannot use a `preBuildCommand` in my context as I don't have a binary to execute but a target. Also I discovered that on Xcode 15 this issue is also for `preBuildCommand`

Comment: Indeed. I am also facing similar issue while using swiftgen prebuild command plugin on Xcode Cloud for Xcode 15. I am also wondering if there is some permission  defaults i can set in post-clone script

Comment: I have the same issue after updating to Xcode 15. Please let me know, if you find a solution. I haven't been able to find one yet :/

Comment: @NicolaiHarbo I found a solution for my case!